# C++ map template and primitive types

Tags: stl, dictionary, primitive-types

I'm not familiar with STL and my brain is bugging with the map template. Is it ok to declare a variable as `map<unsigned long, const char*>` ? Can I call the `clear()` function with such a type ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

I guess your concern may be about whether `delete` is invoked on each `const char *` when you call `clear()`.  The answer to that is: no.